# How long does it take to refresh a full copy sandbox?

Tags: soap-api

I started the FC1 Sandbox refresh today morning at 9 AM, but the status is still showing as in queue.I wanted to check why is it taking so long.
usually by this time it used to show the processing % atleast

Answer (score 1):

The system can only create so many sandboxes at a time. As such, there is a queue to create sandboxes. This queue can be backed up by hours or even days. It's not unusual for this to happen especially shortly before and after releases. There's no SLA for the timing, but if you're concerned that something is wrong, you can always contact support.